# Indexing a BitArray where bits are defined by a generic Enum

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I'm working with pulling a stream of bytes off of a medical device, and have run into a really annoying data structure. Basically, I am getting back a 2-byte chunk where each bit represents a boolean value. This structure appears frequently enough in the byte stream to develop a struct/class around it, but in each instance, the bits mean completely different things.

So first I set up a bunch of Enums to represent all the different definitions the bit structure could have. (Note that not every bit is used in every definition. Sometimes there are breaks in between the important bits.)

**EDIT:** Removed all names that looked like 'flag.' I'm not using the [Flags] attribute, and this seems to be a point of contention/confusion. The enum values are simply mapped to the indices in my BitArray.

```
public enum RecordInfo { AM_TEST = 0, PM_TEST, TEST_VALIDITY };
public enum RecordAlerts { ALERT1 = 0, ALERT2, ALERT3, ALERT4, VALIDATED = 15 };
```

Then created this container to hold the actual bits:

```
public struct TwoBytes<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    private BitArray _bits = new BitArray(2);
}
```

This seems to work as I need, until I want to index my structure based on an Enum name. So say I have a TwoByte struct called Alerts, and this contains some bit values. If I want to get a specific flag like this:

```
bool alert3Set = Alerts[RecordAlerts.ALERT3]
```

I end up with a truly heinous index function. This is what I have in place now:

```
public bool this[TEnum name]
{
    get
    {
        int index = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>().ToList().Where(x => x.Equals(name)).Cast<int>().First();
        return _bits[index];
    }
}
```

Now it works, crazily enough. But that LINQ chains looks positively atrocious, and it takes a while to decipher what it's actually doing.

Is there a cleaner, more efficient way of converting a generic Enum 'name' to its integer value? Or would I be better suited to use a Dictionary (or some other object) to represent the bit structure definitions?

Comment: While this is a seemingly good question, due to the fact that you say it works, and there's no errors, this seems more like a question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not use the [Flags] annotation for the enums and directly use bit masks like `{ FLAG1 = 1, FLAG2 = 2, FLAG3 = 4, FLAG4 = 8 }` with the values being powers of two?

Comment: There's something really wrong with this question.  These enums are missing the [Flags] attribute.  A value of type RecordFlags can never store more than *one* flag unambiguously.  Enum.GetName() already solves that.

Comment: @Hans Passant I'm not familiar with the [Flags] attribute. The fact that my enum ended up using the word Flags is completely unintentional.

Comment: Well, nobody is stopping you from having a look at your favorite C# language book.  But as you've written the code, Enum.GetName() is all you'll ever need.

Comment: @FrankPl Thank you for pointing me in that direction. I have no familiarity with [Flags] or bit masks, so looks like I'll be doing some reading this afternoon. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as every `TEnum` you'd use derives from `int` (the default), and not from another number type, this will work:

```
public bool this[TEnum name]
{
    get
    {
        int index = (int)(object)name;
        return _bits[index];
    }
}
```

If you want to support `enum`s derived from smaller types (and enums that only use values within the range supported by `int`), I'd use:

```
public bool this[TEnum name]
{
    get
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(name);
        return _bits[index];
    }
}
```

(fully supporting enums derived from types that can't implicitly be converted to `int`, like `uint`, `long`, and `ulong`, gets more complicated, because `BitArray`'s indexer uses an `int`)

Comment: Wow... (int)(object)name completely replaced my horrible LINQ chain. This is humbling. Thank you.

Comment: @MadHenchbot overthinking happens to the best of us. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think a bit of OOP would make your life easier. You can introduces classes that represent the data you receive, and has meaningful property names. Each class could accept your BitArray into constructor and parse it into properties.

Further in your program you could use these classes instead of fiddling with bits.

Comment: I am converting the results of this into structured classes further down the line, but in this data layer I'm reading bytes in a very generic way, ie: Read<T>(int size). The fewer things I allow T to accept, the better. Still, a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

As FrankPI suggested in the comments, why not use an `enum` whose values really represent each bit, rather than using an intermediate `BitArray`?

```
[Flags]
public enum RecordFlags { FLAG1 = 0x1, FLAG2 = 0x2, FLAG3 = 0x4, FLAG4 = 0x8, FLAG5 = 0x10, VALIDATED = 0x8000 };

var readFlags = (RecordFlags) ((bytes[0] << 8) | bytes[1]);
bool hasFlag2 = (readFlags & RecordFlags.Flag2) != 0;
```

Comment: Very cool! I honestly didn't know I could do something like this.